# can i append a variable to the url in my .load method as well as load in a specific portion of the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do the following:

`instance.selectors.banner.load('http://localhost/wcd/html/'+url '#inner');`

which appends the href of the link clicked and loads in #inner of the selected document. I get an error in the console though that says there is an unexpected token ). Is what I'm doing possible or what could I do to achieve this?

Comment: you have a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a + operator.

Here is the corrected code:

```
instance.selectors.banner.load('http://localhost/wcd/html/' + url + '#inner');
```